# Return image using MVC Action Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have scenario to return Images using action filter before hit the Specific action. Can we achieve this using action filters? Here we return image as content, if we encounter any image files in url, otherwise pass to respective action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Consider this as an example:

```
public class MyFileFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // imagine in your route data you have a key named file 
        // which contain file name
        // if you want access to request url to check if it is a file use
        // filterContext.HttpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
        // property instead

        if (filterContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("file"))
        {
           // very simple example how to find file on the server 
            string physicalFilePath=HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                 filterContext.RouteData.Values["file"].ToString());


           // if your url matches and you found a file set
           // filterContext.Result value otherwise nothing.
           if(File.Exists(physicalFilePath))
           {
               // also you must send a proper content type for each file.
               filterContext.Result = new FilePathResult(physicalFilePath, "YourFileContentType");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end simply use your Attribute:

```
[MyFileFilter]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    // your code
}
```